# setting background Image disturbs the layout in tab activity

Tags: android, tabs, styles, background-image

I am having an activity that have tabs in it. the layout works fine when I am not using app background  as image with below code.

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
      <!--  <item name="android:background">@drawable/imagese4copy</item>
         All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
```

and layout looks like :
[image]

and when I include background image it looks like :
[image]

here is my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends  TabActivity {
    private TabHost tabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources resource = getResources();
        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();


        Intent intentHelper = new Intent(this, Helper.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHelper = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Helper")
                .setIndicator("",
                        resource.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(intentHelper);

        Intent intentRequest = new Intent(this, HelpRequest.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecRequest = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("HelpRequest")
                .setIndicator("",
                        resource.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(intentRequest);

        Intent intentSetting = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecSetting = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Setting")
                .setIndicator("",
                        resource.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(intentSetting);

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHelper);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecRequest);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecSetting);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
```

and `activity_main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest.HelpRequest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help_request" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest.Helper"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_helper" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please tell me what is going wrong when I include background image and how can I rectify it.

Regards,
Sourabh

Comment: and what changes at code when You set background?

Comment: when I just add `<item name="android:background">@drawable/imagese4copy</item>` and the unwanted layout comes

Comment: ok, but where do You have set the style?

Comment: in manifest file. Actually I want this theme to be applied in all activity.

Comment: What happens if You try to set this, with another theme and without the comments inside?: <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Black"> <item name="android:background">@drawable/imagese4copy</item> </style> note this is not an answer but I need to show the code...

Comment: nothing happens.. same as above

Comment: this is very suspicious....could You check it on a real device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research in [android dev guide](http://devloper.android.com) I found that if you apply background Image in application it will set background to all View in application. As Tab and TextView are a View they also have backgroundImage and hence because of it disturbs the layout.

I don't know if there is any more perfect solution available but setting background Image to LinearLayout or RelativeLayout will solve the problem but you have to apply this on each xml file to get same background in all activity.

example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_darkgreyrough"
    tools:context=".Overview" >
```